# For which periodic sequences $(a_n)$ does the series $\sum \frac{a_n}n$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, conditional-convergence

Let $(a_n)$ be some sequence of real (or maybe even complex) numbers. For which sequences does

$$S=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}n$$

converge to a finite value?

Let $p$ denote the period of $a_n$, i.e. $a_n = a_{n+p}$ for all $n$.

- **$\large{p=1}$**

  The series $S$ will only converge if $a_1=0$ because otherwise, $S$ is the Harmonic series.
- **$\large{p=2}$**

  The series will converge if $a_2=-a_1$. Then the series converges to $S= a_1\ln 2$. If $a_2=-a_1+\Delta$ then $S$ can be split into two series, one converging to $a_1\ln 2$, and one diverging like $\Delta$ times the harmonic series.
- **$\large{p\geqslant3}$**

  For this case I have only the  conjecture that $$S \text{  converges } \quad\iff\quad \sum_{n=1}^p a_n = 0$$ but I have no idea how to proceed?

Comment: One way the implication is true. There is a Dirichlet criterion: if the partial sums of $a_n$ are bounded and $b_n $ tends to $0$ and is decreasing then the series $\sum a_nb_n$ is convergent. Also the other direction is true, as the series can be bounded below by the harmonic series if the sum is positive.

Comment: this is well known as it follows from summation by parts (if $\sum_{n=1}^p a_n=c \ne 0$, then taking $b_n=a_n-c/p$ we have that $\sum_{n=1}^p b_n=0$ so $\sum b_n/n$ converges by summation by parts, but $\sum a_n/n -\sum b_n/n$ is a non zero multiple of the harmonic series so cannot converge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked this out before.
The sum converges if and only if
$A=\sum_{k=1}^p a_k = 0
$.

This can be proved by
looking at each group of
$p$ consecutive terms
starting at $n$
and subtracting
$\frac{A}{n}$.

I'll work out the details if you want.